# Generate an ordred random values

Tags: java, random

How generate a random values **Ordered** between 0 and 1 without make a test `if` at each iteration?

```
0.01
0.12
0.2
0.33
...
```

Comment: you have some best solutions, (which i can't reach with my knowledge). Try to accept them

Answer (score 3):

You can use [TreeSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeSet.html)

> A Set that further provides a total ordering on its elements. The
>   elements are ordered using their natural ordering, or by a Comparator
>   typically provided at sorted set creation time. The set's iterator
>   will traverse the set in ascending element order

E.g.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SortedSet<Float> randoms = new TreeSet<Float>();
    Random random = new Random();
    while(randoms.size() < 5) {
        randoms.add(random.nextFloat());
    }
    for(Float r: randoms) {
        System.out.println(r);
    }
}
```

Output

```
0.017743647
0.1998645
0.37926406
0.39519936
0.7745726
```

EDIT:
If generate random number by order where next random number is depends on previous number, I dont think it is random number.

Comment: TreeSet ordred value at last of generation and not when values are generated !

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you want:

a) make n random numbers and sort them

b) in order to make the next random number create a random number, multiply with (1- last number) and add the last number.

Note that the resulting distribution is very different

Answer (score 2):

The following code guarantees that each next number will be greater than previous. And the number are random. Is it good for you?

```
Random r = new Random();
double[] results = new double[n];
double prev = 0;
for (int i = 0;  i < n;  i++) {
    double next = prev + r.nextDouble();
    results[i] = next;
    prev = next;
}
```

The disadvantage is that the numbers a not limited by any predefined threshold. If you need this, I'd recommend you just to generate the array of numbers and then sort it using `Arrays.sort()` (as many other guys recommended).

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that by ordered you mean sorted, you could create a series of random numbers, add them to a collection and then sort it.